# A div out of 3 others. That shows up while the others are invisible. (When pressed on button)

Tags: javascript, html

so I have 3 divs right now:

```js
    var t1 = document.getElementById("tafel1");
    var t2 = document.getElementById("tafel2");
    var t3 = document.getElementById("tafel3");

    function tafel1() {
        if (t1.style.display === "none") {
            t1.style.display = "block";
        } else {
            t1.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
    function tafel2(){
        if (t2.style.display === "none") {
            t2.style.display = "block";
        } else {
            t2.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
    function tafel3(){
        if (t3.style.display === "none") {
            t3.style.display = "block";
        } else {
            t3.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
```

```css
div{
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="tafel1">
        Tafel 1
    </div>
    <div id="tafel2">
        Tafel 2
    </div>
    <div id="tafel3">
        Tafel 3
    </div>
    <button onclick="tafel1()">Tafel oefening 1</button>
    <button onclick="tafel2()">Tafel oefening 2</button>
    <button onclick="tafel3()">Tafel oefening 3</button>
```

What I want is that if you press on 1 button 1 box opens at a time.
So you'll be able to see only 1 box when pressed on the button for it. And the other 2 will be invisible. but when pressed on the other button the other box will appear. while the other 2 will be invisible again.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

[Working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dhakim/fc5szg4s/)

You can modify your big function to a below small JavaScript function with a help of little CSS and some modification in function call on button click

**HTML**

```
<div id="tafel1" class="hide">Tafel 1</div>
<div id="tafel2" class="hide">Tafel 2</div>
<div id="tafel3" class="hide">Tafel 3</div>
<button onclick="footafel('1')">Tafel oefening 1</button>
<button onclick="footafel('2')">Tafel oefening 2</button>
<button onclick="footafel('3')">Tafel oefening 3</button>
```

**Javascript**

```
function footafel(id){  
  for(var i=1; i<=3; i++){
    document.getElementById('tafel'+i).className = 'hide';
  }
  if(id == ''){
    return false;
  } else {
    document.getElementById('tafel'+id).className = 'show';
  }
}
```

**CSS**

```
.hide { display: none; }
.show { display: block; }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to display one of your `tafel*` divs, you need to hide all the other ones.

```
function tafel1() {
    // Hide other divs
    t2.style.display = "none";
    t3.style.display = "none";

    if (t1.style.display === "none") {
        t1.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        t1.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Hiding a already hidden element does not do anything so you don't need to check first before hiding.

Comment: this way you are hidding all the divs until the user click twice in the button

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the other two when clicked on a button

```
function tafel1() {
    t1.style.display = "block"; 
    t2.style.display = "none";
    t3.style.display = "none";         
}
function tafel2() {
    t1.style.display = "none";
    t2.style.display = "block"; 
    t3.style.display = "none";         
}
function tafel3() {
    t1.style.display = "none";
    t2.style.display = "none";
    t3.style.display = "block";
}
```

Comment: this make available div to vanish on 2nd click

Comment: Edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

you want to show only clicked button's div

```
function tafel1() {
       t3.style.display = "none";
       t2.style.display = "none";
       t1.style.display = "block";

}
```

similarly for other three

snipper for you

```js
var t1 = document.getElementById("tafel1");
var t2 = document.getElementById("tafel2");
var t3 = document.getElementById("tafel3");

function tafel1() {
    t3.style.display = "none";
       t2.style.display = "none";
       t1.style.display = "block";
       console.log('tafel 1');
}
function tafel2(){
    t3.style.display = "none";
       t2.style.display = "block";
       t1.style.display = "none";
       console.log('tafel 2');
}
function tafel3(){
    t3.style.display = "block";
       t2.style.display = "none";
       t1.style.display = "none";
       console.log('tafel 3');
}
```

```css
div{
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid;
  margin:2px;
}
```

```html
<div id="tafel1">
        Tafel 1
    </div>
    <div id="tafel2">
        Tafel 2
    </div>
    <div id="tafel3">
        Tafel 3
    </div>
    <button onclick="tafel1()">Tafel oefening 1</button>
    <button onclick="tafel2()">Tafel oefening 2</button>
    <button onclick="tafel3()">Tafel oefening 3</button>
```

Comment: @Derman  as you are new to stack overflow take aa tour to earn a badge https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

Like this?
I modified your if-statement in a way that if you click for the first time, only the selected DIV will be shown, if you click again, it resets and show all divs.
take a look and run the snippet, please.

```js
var t1 = document.getElementById("tafel1");
    var t2 = document.getElementById("tafel2");
    var t3 = document.getElementById("tafel3");

    function tafel1() {
        if (t2.style.display === "none" || t3.style.display === "none"){
          t2.style.display = "block";
          t3.style.display = "block";        
        }else{
          t1.style.display = "block";
          t2.style.display = "none";
          t3.style.display = "none";         
        }
    }
    
    function tafel2(){      
        if (t1.style.display === "none" || t3.style.display === "none"){
          t1.style.display = "block";
          t3.style.display = "block";        
        }else{
          t2.style.display = "block";
          t1.style.display = "none";
          t3.style.display = "none";     
        }
    }
    function tafel3(){     
        if (t1.style.display === "none" || t2.style.display === "none"){
          t1.style.display = "block";
          t2.style.display = "block";        
        }else{
          t3.style.display = "block";
          t1.style.display = "none";
          t2.style.display = "none";    
        }
    }
```

```css
div{
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="tafel1">
        Tafel 1
    </div>
    <div id="tafel2">
        Tafel 2
    </div>
    <div id="tafel3">
        Tafel 3
    </div>
    <button onclick="tafel1()">Tafel oefening 1</button>
    <button onclick="tafel2()">Tafel oefening 2</button>
    <button onclick="tafel3()">Tafel oefening 3</button>
```